# Several one to many relationships between two tables Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have Guest Entity

```
public class Guest
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
```

I need an Entity that describes relationshipType between two guests. I came up with

```
public class RelationshipGuestLink
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Relationship Relationship { get; set; }
        public Guid RelationshipId { get; set; }
        public Guest FirstGuest { get; set; }
        public Guid FirstGuestId { get; set; }
        public Guest SecondGuest { get; set; }
        public Guid SecondGuestId { get; set; }
        public ProfileRelationshipType RelationshipType { get; set; }
        public Guid RelationshipTypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

And map them using fluentApi

```
public RelationshipGuestLinkConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("MyTable");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        HasOptional(x => x.Relationship).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.RelationshipId);
        HasOptional(x => x.FirstGuest).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.FirstGuestId);
        HasOptional(x => x.SecondGuest).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.SecondGuestId);
        HasOptional(x => x.RelationshipType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.RelationshipTypeId);
    }
```

Problem is, I don't know what to do with `WithMany()` part. Do I have to create two `ICollection<RelationshipGuestLink>` in `Guest` class? Or can I map them to one collection?

In the end I need to create something like family, and be able to access family members from any member of a family.

EDIT: Thanks to Vidmantas Blazevicius for help. 
I moved `RelationshipType` to `Relationship` class, as it belong there. And without it felt empty and useless. Also renamed my First and Second guests to something more appropriate.

My problem is with my mania to write down every link in models with fluentApi from two sides of the problem. I see those links as Foreign keys, and as my `RelationshipGuestLink` table has two keys to `Guest` table, I tried to create two links in EF.

But I still think one link will only get me the relatives of the first Guest. And to get his whole family I'll have to write additional code to walk this tree and create a `List<Guest>`

Comment: Quite puzzled at what you are trying to achieve here with the fluentApi. `RelationshipGuestLinkConfiguration` should have a PK, M:1 FK to RelationshipType, 1:M FK to Guest for FirstGuest and 1:M FK to Guest for second guest. What for do you need two `ICollection` since this is a joining table`?

Comment: "In the end I need to create something like family, and be able to access family members from any member of a family."  Why not have a family Id value on each guest?  Are the relationships strictly binary(related or not-related)?  If you need to know where the person falls in a family hierarchy (father, son, brother, etc), create a lookup table and then add another column to guest named relationshipposition (or whatever works for you).  I think you may be over complicating something that can be fixed with a lookup table and a lookupId column.

Comment: @user7396598 This Relationship is a Family of some sort. It can be Collegues, Friends, etc.. So I called it Relationship. Now I can tell that GuestA and GuestB are connected with each other with Family Relationship type. But so are GuestA and GuestC. And I needed to get GuestB from GuestC, that is when this Link object came to life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish and a single `ICollection<RelationshipGuestLink>` should be sufficient. By doing this you achieve a 1:M with your joining table `RelationshipGuestLink`.

```
    public class Guest
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RelationshipGuestLink> RelationshipLinks { get; set; }
    }
```

So if the example is a Child, Father and Mother - all being instances of the Guest class - you would have two relationship links for Child (to the father and the mother), one for each parent (relating to each other).

**EDIT:**

Below is how I imagine your model builder looking for `RelationshipGuestLink`. It should be as simple as that. There is M:1 relationship from this table to the `Guest` table in terms of foreign key `GuestId`. Same for `RelatedGuest`. Your `Relationship` property is really only going to be on one end. Whilst it also M:1 relationship with the `Relationship` table - you don't really want to have `ICollection<RelationshipGuestLink>` on your Relationship` entity class because, but you do want that the foreign key exists. Whether you want to cascade on delete (which is highly advisable in most cases) - it is up to you.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<RelationshipGuestLink>()
            .HasKey(x => x.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RelationshipGuestLink>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Guest).WithMany(x => x.RelationshipLinks).HasForeignKey(x => x.Guest);

        modelBuilder.Entity<RelationshipGuestLink>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Relationship).WithRequiredDependent();

    }

    public class RelationshipGuestLink
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid GuestId { get; set; }
        public Guid RelationshipId { get; set; }
        public Guid RelatedGuestId { get; set; }

        public Guest Guest { get; set; }
        public Relationship Relationship { get; set; }
        public Guest RelatedGuest { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Ty for response. So I shall have only one `WithMany()` block populated?

`HasOptional(x => x.FirstGuest).WithMany(g => g.RelationshipLinks ).HasForeignKey(x => x.FirstGuestId);

        HasOptional(x => x.SecondGuest).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.SecondGuestId);`

Or both of them linked to one collection in the `Guest` class?

Comment: @AleksandrAzimov Get rid of `RelationshipType` because that relation belongs to `Relationship` table (which in turns has a property `RelationshipType`. `Relationship` then is not `WithMany()` but `HasRequired(x => x.Relationship)` because that is M:1 relationship. Lastly, same with FirstGuest and SecondGuest (should rename those really to Guest and RelatedGuest or smth like that). Let me know if anything else is unclear.

Comment: You are right, I will rename Guests. RelationshipType's place is in relationship, but I still don't quite get configuration part. Should I link RelationshipLinks to one guest, or to both of them? It should be linked to both of them logically, but I don't wish to have two collections on the `Guest` side

Comment: @AleksandrAzimov I've edited of what I think your model builder should look like

Comment: @AleksandrAzimov had a second read through your question, I can certainly understand why you are asking this now. But why would you need a second collection if your first collection will technically already hold the items that the second collection would. Think of Son-Father relationship, your single collection will hold the relation that Son is related to the Father and it doesn't need to hold that Father is related to Son because that is just implicit and duplicate. Hope that makes sense.